# Only white and green wire from ceiling. No black?

Tags: ceiling-fan

Installing ceiling fan. House built in 1944. The wires from the ceiling are green and white. No black wire. The old fan I took down looks like the blue and black fan wires were connected to the white wire. I have included a photo of what I’m seeing. Perhaps someone could help.

[image]

Comment: With the power off, reach up into the junction box and feel around for more wires.

Comment: It is possible that one of those wires is used as hot and there is no ground wire.  Which wire is hot, might depend if they used same wire colour to the fuse/breaker box.

Comment: it looks like green is ground and attached to the bracket. how many white wires are there?

Comment: There is only 1 white wire from the ceiling. This white wire is silver, not copper.

Comment: What was the green wire connected to on the old fan?

Comment: Yes, the green wires were together.

Comment: Suffice it to say, that mounting bracket is *not* supposed to be buried behind drywall!  Can you get us better views of what's going on inside that box, especially at the point where the white wire enters the box?

Comment: Is there a wall switch for this fan, or is it controlled purely by switches/cords on the fan unit itself?  If there's a wall switch, see what color wires leave the switch.   But further,  1940 wiring is unlikely to be up to modern code, so you may want to consider having an electrician run proper wiring (hot, neutral, ground) to the fan mount.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to resign yourself to removing some more ceiling drywall material.

You must find out where that white wire goes, why it's not in a cable or conduit, and why there's no black wire. You also want to make sure that the bracket installation is strong enough to hold a ceiling fan, and correctly install the proper fan-rated junction box.

You're not going to do that through the tiny hole you now have.

Start with that obvious patch material toward the top of your picture. I think you'll find that replacing a 16" x 16" section of ceiling is not really any harder than replacing a 5" x 5" section.

Comment: If this was wired up in the original house (1940), codes and colors were different to say the least.

Comment: I wasn’t replacing or removing drywall. The hole was already there. What you’re suggesting is a huge project. I don’t kno the 1st thing about drywall and creating a huge hole in the ceiling that I don’t kno how to fix makes me think I should just not put up anything.

Comment: @Angela -- the hole in the ceiling's a lot easier to fix than the consequences of screwed-up wiring

Comment: That is true but my budget will not allow me to do these things. I’ll go take another look at it and see

Comment: Ok I reached up in and then the top of the junction box. There is no black wire. The white wire is connected to an older cloth (?) covered cord that goes into the darkness. That’s it. Nothing else. The green wire is connected to the hanging bracket. This fan had been hooked up for 6 years without issue, so I know it CAN  be connected, but should it be connected that way again?

Comment: That fan has turned all your house wiring into an electrocution hazard for at least six years. You have been lucky. -